# Search for a particular control from ControlCollection using LINQ or any fast way

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have a set of control collection, and I am looking for a way to get a particular control by ID added at runtime, is there any fast, optimized way to do this?

Here is a code:

```
HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
row.ID = string.Format("tr{0}", key);
tableParameters.Rows.Add(row);

HtmlTableCell cellParameterName = new HtmlTableCell();
cellParameterName.ID = string.Format("td{0}", key);
row.Cells.Add(cellParameterName);

Label lblParameterName = new Label();
lblParameterName.ID = string.Format("lblParameter{0}", key);
cellParameterName.Controls.Add(lblParameterName);
lblParameterName.Text = key + ":";

HtmlTableCell cellParameterSelectionControl = new HtmlTableCell();
cellParameterSelectionControl.ID = string.Format("tdSelectionControl{0}", parameterInfos[key].ParameterName);
row.Cells.Add(cellParameterSelectionControl);
```

Thanx

Comment: what do you mean by `ID`? Controls don't have an `ID` property.

Comment: Nested controls or siblings only?  winforms controls or asp server controls?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the program? Winforms? ASP.NET? Please show us the code you wrote.

Comment: @Jodrell I added that control at run time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [`Control.FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)?

Supose your table ID is `tableExample`:

```
var tr = tableExample.FindControl("tr5");
```

But remember that it isn't recursive. So, if you want to get the `lblParameter5`, you could find each parent first until that element:

```
var tr = tableExample.FindControl("tr5") as HtmlTableRow;
var td = tr.FindControl("td5") as HtmlTableCell;
var lbl = td.FindControl("lblParemeter5") as Label;
```

Or you can create a recursive function that do it to you. Here is a sample using extension methods to create this recursive function:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Control FindById(this Page p, string id)
    {
        return FindControlRecursive(p, id);
    }

    private static Control FindByIdRecursive(Control root, string id)
    {
        if (root.ID == id)
            return root;

        foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
        {
            Control c2 = FindByIdRecursive(c, id);
            if (c2 != null)
                return t;
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

So, your call just be:

```
var lbl = FindById("lblParameter5") as Label;
```

Comment: Is this will search in whole DOM?

Comment: I updated my code showing a recursive approach that search the whole DOM like you desire.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you create an extension method for `Page`? `Page` inherits from `Control`; so, it should have access to the second method.

Comment: I'm not extending `Control`, so the method isn't being appended to that class (and to its subclasses), because I don't needed all controls with this behavior. But off course, the first method could have `Control` as the first parameter if wanted to add the `FindById()` method to all controls instead of just to the `Page` class.